# Manipulating results from eloquent query laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I would like to have a custom json response from the results of eloquent. SO basically I have a table that list all the fields like this:

```
userid
name
address1
address2
state
city
zip
```

Then using a query like this:

```
$results = User::paginate(10);
```

Then I would like to have a custom response from the $results like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "AddressInfo" {
            "address1" : "some address1 here...",
            "address2" : "some address2 here...",
            "state" : "TX",
            "city" : "San Antonio",
            "zip" : "12345" 
        }
    },
    {
        //other records...
    }
]
```

My current solutions is to do the foreach()

```
foreach($result as $k=>$v){
    $arrItem = [
        'id' => $v->userid,
        'AddressInfo' => [ ... ]
    ]
}
```

Code above is working but thinking using different approach and optimization like map() in laravel.

Anyone knows how to achieve the output.

Thanks

Comment: You should look at using `Transformers` http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/, There is a package to help you use it in laravel here https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal